# What is the relation between transactions, commands and connections?

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope, sqlconnection

Follow what the code do:

1. A transaction scope is created.
2. A connection is created and opened enlisting it in the transaction
   scope created en step 1.
3. A command is submitted using the already opened connection.
4. The connection is closed.
5. A new transaction scope is created.
6. The same connection is opened what provoke the enlisting of the
   connection in the new transaction created by the new transaction
   scope instance in the step 5.
7. A command is submitted using the already opened connection.
8. The first transaction scope is completed and disposed and just after
   that the second one.

What happens with the same command executed on that connection? Are those commands committed even the connection was closed before call `Complete();` and `Dispose();` on the first transaction scope?

What I think is that transactions aren't managed by connections at all, and even a connection is used by two transactions, the commands sent to different transactions aren't related at all not matter them were sent to the server using the same connection. I'm right?

Follow the code:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
     traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE CREATE THE TRANSACTION SCOPE, OPEN AND USE THE CONNECTION");
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CLEAR_CONNECTION_STRING);
     connection.Open();
     ExecuteCommand1(connection);
     connection.Close();
     traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "AFTER CREATE THE TRANSACTION SCOPE, OPEN THE CONNECTION, USES IT AND CLOSE IT.");

     traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE CALL TransactionScope transactionScope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew); .");

     using (TransactionScope transactionScope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
     {
         traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE CALL connection.Open(); .");
         connection.Open();
         traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE EXECUTE THE SECOND COMMAND.");
         ExecuteCommand2(connection);
         traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE CLOSE THE CONNECTION.");
         connection.Close();
         traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "AFTER CLOSE THE CONNECTION.");

         traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE transactionScope2.Complete(); .");
         transactionScope2.Complete();
     }             

     traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE transactionScope1.Complete(); .");
     transactionScope1.Complete();
     traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "BEFORE transactionScope1.Dispose(); .");
 }
```

Follow the Log content:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.7789227Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE CREATE THE TRANSACTION SCOPE, OPEN AND USE THE CONNECTION</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.7799199Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/TransactionCreated</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Transaction Created</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/TransactionCreatedTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Lightweight]</TraceSource>
            <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:16</TransactionIdentifier>
              <CloneIdentifier>1</CloneIdentifier>
            </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.7809183Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/TransactionScopeCreated</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>TransactionScope Created</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/TransactionScopeCreatedTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Base]</TraceSource>
            <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:16</TransactionIdentifier>
              <CloneIdentifier>2</CloneIdentifier>
            </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
            <TransactionScopeResult>CreatedTransaction</TransactionScopeResult>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.7819208Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/Enlistment</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Enlistment Created</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/EnlistmentTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Lightweight]</TraceSource>
            <EnlistmentTraceIdentifier>
              <ResourceManagerId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ResourceManagerId>
              <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
                <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:16</TransactionIdentifier>
                <CloneIdentifier>2</CloneIdentifier>
              </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <EnlistmentIdentifier>0</EnlistmentIdentifier>
            </EnlistmentTraceIdentifier>
            <EnlistmentType>PromotableSinglePhase</EnlistmentType>
            <EnlistmentOptions>None</EnlistmentOptions>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8400190Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>AFTER CREATE THE TRANSACTION SCOPE, OPEN THE CONNECTION, USES IT AND CLOSE IT.</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8412412Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE CALL TransactionScope transactionScope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew); .</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8422462Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/TransactionCreated</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Transaction Created</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/TransactionCreatedTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Lightweight]</TraceSource>
            <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:17</TransactionIdentifier>
              <CloneIdentifier>1</CloneIdentifier>
            </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8432442Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/TransactionScopeCreated</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>TransactionScope Created</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/TransactionScopeCreatedTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Base]</TraceSource>
            <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:17</TransactionIdentifier>
              <CloneIdentifier>2</CloneIdentifier>
            </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
            <TransactionScopeResult>CreatedTransaction</TransactionScopeResult>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8442750Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE CALL connection.Open(); .</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8452783Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/Enlistment</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Enlistment Created</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/EnlistmentTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Lightweight]</TraceSource>
            <EnlistmentTraceIdentifier>
              <ResourceManagerId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ResourceManagerId>
              <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
                <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:17</TransactionIdentifier>
                <CloneIdentifier>2</CloneIdentifier>
              </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <EnlistmentIdentifier>0</EnlistmentIdentifier>
            </EnlistmentTraceIdentifier>
            <EnlistmentType>PromotableSinglePhase</EnlistmentType>
            <EnlistmentOptions>None</EnlistmentOptions>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8462788Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE EXECUTE THE SECOND COMMAND.</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8522799Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE CLOSE THE CONNECTION.</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8532787Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>AFTER CLOSE THE CONNECTION.</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8532787Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE transactionScope2.Complete(); .</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8542792Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE transactionScope2.Dispose(); .</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8552784Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/TransactionScopeDisposed</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>TransactionScope Disposed</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/TransactionScopeDisposedTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Base]</TraceSource>
            <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:17</TransactionIdentifier>
              <CloneIdentifier>2</CloneIdentifier>
            </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8562814Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE transactionScope1.Complete(); .</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8572798Z" />
    <Source Name="TransactionsLab" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>BEFORE transactionScope1.Dispose(); .</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8582802Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="10" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/2004/06/System/Transactions/TransactionScopeDisposed</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>TransactionScope Disposed</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/TransactionScopeDisposedTraceRecord">
            <TraceSource>[Base]</TraceSource>
            <TransactionTraceIdentifier>
              <TransactionIdentifier>5a0cb948-beb4-4143-bccb-4dbd575daf55:16</TransactionIdentifier>
              <CloneIdentifier>2</CloneIdentifier>
            </TransactionTraceIdentifier>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-19T20:32:30.8672795Z" />
    <Source Name="System.Transactions" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="TransactionsLab.vshost" ProcessID="11004" ThreadID="2" />
    <Channel/>
    <Computer>PCNAME</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Diagnostics/AppDomainUnload</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>AppDomain unloading.</Description>
          <AppDomain>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/03/Transactions/DictionaryTraceRecord">
            <AppDomain.FriendlyName>TransactionsLab.vshost.exe</AppDomain.FriendlyName>
            <ProcessName>TransactionsLab.vshost</ProcessName>
            <ProcessId>11004</ProcessId>
          </ExtendedData>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: That code is really hard to read. Can't you reformat to properly nest scopes using `using`?

Comment: @DJKRAZE Yes, I looked the MSDN documentation and search in Google, but the information that I found there don't answer me clearly the questions I put here.

Comment: @usr I edited the code, let me know if is more clear for you now. Thanks. The trace messages clutter the code a little, but them are very important to see what is happening, I mean, to know what the effect of the c# sentences are in the transaction manager, who is logging to the same file.

Comment: It looks like you left out the call that executes the second command as well (step 7).

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Code and log edited, no change at all but you are right, coping pasting code I forgot about that call ;)